# PHP Form Not Displaying With jQuery Mobile

Tags: php, jquery, forms, jquery-mobile

Part of my PHP form is not displaying with jQuery Mobile.  The form seems to cut off after `<input name="F_Payment_Preference" type="hidden" id="F_Payment_Preference" value="check">` and then it restarts after `</form>`. My form seems to function and display correctly without jQuery Mobile.  I am not showing the head of the page (it's in a separate file), but I don't think that is necessary.

">

```
<form action="<? echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="post" name="form1" id="form1" onsubmit="return CheckData();">
 <h1><? echo PERSONAL_INFORMATION
 ?></h1><?
if ($show_sponsor == 1) {
    Get_Sponsor_Cookie('name');
}
?>
<div>
    *<? echo REQUIRED_FIELDS
    ?>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="F_First_Name"><? echo  FIRST_NAME
        ?>*</label>
    <input name="F_First_Name" type="text" value="<? echo $F_First_Name ?>" maxlength="50">
    <div id="divfname" style="display:none;">
        <? echo JV_ENTER_FIRST_NAME
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
<label for="F_Last_Name"><? echo LAST_NAME ?>*</label>
<input name="F_Last_Name" type="text" value="<? echo $F_Last_Name ?>" maxlength="50">
</div>
<div id="divlname" style="display:none">
<? echo JV_ENTER_LAST_NAME
?>
</div>
<?
if ($require_company == 1 || $require_company == 2)
{
?>
<div>
<label for="F_Company_Name"><? echo ROW_COMPANY ?>
<?
if ($require_company == 2) { echo "*";
}
?></label>
<input name="F_Company_Name" type="text" value="<? echo $F_Company_Name ?>" maxlength="100">
</div>
<div id="divcmp" style="display:none">
    <? echo ENTER_COMPANY
    ?>
</div>
<?
}
if ($require_address_1 == 1 || $require_address_1 == 2)
{
?>
<div>
    <label for="F_Address_1"><? echo ADDRESS_1
        ?><?
        if ($require_address_1 == 2) { echo "*";
        }
        ?></label>
</div>
<input name="F_Address_1" type="text" value="<? echo $F_Address_1 ?>" maxlength="200">
<div id="divaddr1" style="display:none">
    <? echo JV_ENTER_ADDRESS_1
    ?>
</div>
<?
}
if ($require_address_2 == 1 || $require_address_2 == 2)
{
?>
<div>
    <label for="F_Address_2"><? echo ADDRESS_2
        ?><?
        if ($require_address_2 == 2) { echo "*";
        }
        ?></label>
    <input name="F_Address_2" type="text" value="<? echo $F_Address_2 ?>" maxlength="200">
</div>
<div id="divaddr2" style="display:none">
    <? echo JV_ENTER_ADDRESS_2
    ?>
</div>
<?
}
if ($require_city == 1 || $require_city == 2)
{
?>
<div>
    <label for="F_City"><? echo ROW_CITY
        ?><?
        if ($require_city == 2) { echo "*";
        }
        ?></label>
    <input name="F_City" type="text" value="<? echo $F_City ?>" maxlength="50">
</div>
<div id="divcity" style="display:none">
    <? echo JV_ENTER_CITY
    ?>
</div>
<?
}
if ($require_ste == 1 || $require_state == 2)
{
?>
<div>
    <label for="F_State"><? echo ROW_STATE
        ?><?
        if ($require_state == 2) { echo "*";
        }
        ?></label>
    <input name="F_State" type="text" value="<? echo $F_State ?>" maxlength="50">
</div>
<div id="divstate" style="display:none">
    <? echo JV_ENTER_STATE
    ?>
</div>
<?
}
if ($require_country == 1 || $require_country == 2)
{
?>
<div>
    <label><? echo ROW_COUNTRY
        ?><?
        if ($require_country == 2) { echo "*";
        }
        ?></label>
    <?
    if (!isset($_POST['F_Country'])) { $F_Country = '';
    } else { $F_Country = $_POST['F_Country'];
    } Country_Menu_Members($F_Country);
    ?>
</div>
<?
}
if ($require_zip == 1 || $require_zip == 2)
{
?>
<div>
    <label for="F_Zip"><? echo ZIP_CODE
        ?><?
        if ($require_zip == 2) { echo "*";
        }
        ?></label>
    <input name="F_Zip" type="text" value="<? echo $F_Zip ?>"  maxlength="25" />
</div>
<div id="divzip" style="display:none">
    <? echo JV_ENTER_ZIP
    ?>
</div>
<?
}
if ($require_phone == 1 || $require_phone == 2)
{
?>
<div>
    <label for="F_Phone"><? echo PHONE
        ?><?
        if ($require_phone == 2) { echo "*";
        }
        ?></label>
    <input name="F_Phone" type="text" value="<? echo $F_Phone ?>" maxlength="25" />
</div>
<div id="divphone" style="display:none">
    <? echo JV_ENTER_PHONE
    ?>
</div>
<?
}
if ($require_fax == 1 || $require_fax == 2)
{
?>
<div>
    <label for="F_Fax"><? echo FAX
        ?><?
        if ($require_fax == 2) { echo "*";
        }
        ?></label>
    <input name="F_Fax" type="text" value="<? echo $F_Fax ?>" maxlength="25" />
</div>
<div id="divfax" style="display:none">
    <? echo ENTER_FAX
    ?>
</div>
<?
}
if ($require_check_name == 1 || $require_check_name == 2)
{
?>
<div>
    <label for="F_Check_Name"><? echo CHECK_NAME
        ?><?
        if ($require_check_name == 2) { echo "*";
        }
        ?></label>
    <input name="F_Check_Name" type="text" value="<? echo $F_Check_Name ?>" maxlength="50" />
</div>
<div id="divcheckname" style="display:none">
    <? echo ENTER_CHECK_NAME
    ?>
</div>
<?
}
if ($show_payment == 1)
{
?>
<div>
    <label for="F_Payment_Preference"><? echo PAYMENT_PREFERENCE
        ?>*</label>
    <? Link_Payment_Preferences();?>
    <? } else {?>
    <input name="F_Payment_Preference" type="hidden" id="F_Payment_Preference" value="check" />
</div>
<?
}
if ($require_tax_id == 1 || $require_tax_id == 2)
{
?>
<div>
    <label for="F_Tax_ID"><? echo TAX_ID
        ?><?
        if ($require_tax_id == 2) { echo "*";
        }
        ?></label>
    <input name="F_Tax_ID" type="text" value="<? echo $F_Tax_ID ?>" maxlength="50" />
</div>
<div id="divtax" style="display:none">
    <? echo INVALID_TAX_ID
    ?>
</div>
<?
}
?> <h2><? echo USER_ACCOUNT_INFORMATION
?></h2>
<?
if ($require_username == 1 || $require_username == 2)
 {
 ?>
 <div>
 <label for="F_User_Name"><? echo USERNAME
 ?>
 <?
 if ($require_username == 2) { echo "*";
 }
 ?></label>
 <input name="F_User_Name" type="text" value="<? echo $F_User_Name ?>"  maxlength="20" />
</div>
<div id="divuname" style="display:none">
    <? echo JV_ENTER_USERNAME
    ?>
</div>
<?
}
if ($require_password == 1 || $require_password == 2)
{
?>
<div>
    <label for="F_Password"><? echo PASSWORD
        ?><?
        if ($require_password == 2) { echo "*";
        }
        ?></label>
    <input name="F_Password" type="password" value="<? echo $F_Password ?>"  maxlength="12">
</div>
<div id="divpw" style="display:none">
    <? echo JV_ENTER_PASSWORD
    ?>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="F_Password_2"><? echo CONFIRM_PASSWORD
        ?><?
        if ($require_password == 2) { echo "*";
        }
        ?></label>
    <input name="F_Password_2" type="password" id="password2" value="<? echo $F_Password_2 ?>" maxlength="12">
</div>
<div id="divcpw" style="display:none">
    <? echo JV_ENTER_CONFIRM_PASSWORD
    ?>
</div>
<?
}
?>
<div>
    <label for="F_Primary_Email"><? echo EMAIL_ADDRESS
        ?>*</label>
    <input name="F_Primary_Email" type="email" value="<? echo $F_Primary_Email ?>" maxlength="50">
</div>
<div id="divemail" style="display:none">
    <? echo JV_ENTER_EMAIL
    ?>
</div>
 <?
 if ($require_paypal_email == 1 || $require_paypal_email == 2)
 {
 ?>
 <div>
 <label for="F_Paypal_Email"><? echo PAYPAL_EMAIL
 ?><?
 if ($require_paypal_email == 2) { echo "*";
 }
 ?></label>
 <input name="F_Paypal_Email" type="text" value="<? echo $F_Paypal_Email ?>"  maxlength="50">
</div>
<div id="divpaypal" style="display:none">
    <? echo JV_ENTER_PAYPAL
    ?>
</div>
<?
}
if ($require_stormpay_email == 1 || $require_stormpay_email == 2)
{
?>
<div>
    <label for="F_Stormpay_Email"><? echo STORMPAY_EMAIL
        ?><?
        if ($require_stormpay_email == 2) { echo "*";
        }
        ?></label>
    <input name="F_Stormpay_Email" type="text" value="<? echo $F_Stormpay_Email ?>" maxlength="50">
</div>
<div id="divstormpay" style="display:none">
    <? echo JV_STORMPAY_EMAIL
    ?>
</div>
<?
}
if ($require_safepay_email == 1 || $require_safepay_email == 2)
{
?>
<div>
    <label for="F_Safepay_Email"><? echo SAFEPAY_EMAIL
        ?><?
        if ($require_stormpay_email == 2) { echo "*";
        }
        ?></label>
    <input name="F_Safepay_Email" type="text" value="<? echo $F_Safepay_Email ?>" maxlength="50">
</div>
<div id="divsafepay" style="display:none">
    <? echo JV_SAFEPAY_EMAIL
    ?>
</div>
<?
}
if ($require_moneybookers_email == 1 || $require_moneybookers_email == 2)
{
?>
<div>
    <label for="F_Moneybookers_Email"><? echo MONEYBOOKERS_EMAIL
        ?><?
        if ($require_moneybookers_email == 2) { echo "*";
        }
        ?></label>
    <input name="F_Moneybookers_Email" type="text" value="<? echo $F_Moneybookers_Email ?>" maxlength="50">
</div>
<div id="divmoneybookers" style="display:none">
    <? echo JV_MONEYBOOKERS_EMAIL
    ?>
</div>
<?
}
if ($require_alertpay_email == 1 || $require_alertpay_email == 2)
{
?>
<div>
    <label for="F_Alertpay_Email"><? echo ALERTPAY_EMAIL
        ?><?
        if ($require_alertpay_email == 2) { echo "*";
        }
        ?></label>
    <input name="F_Alertpay_Email" type="text" value="<? echo $F_Alertpay_Email ?>" maxlength="50">
</div>
<div id="divalertpay" style="display:none">
    <? echo JV_ALERTPAY_EMAIL
    ?>
</div>
<?
}
if ($require_egold_id == 1 || $require_egold_id == 2)
{
?>
<div>
    <label for="F_Egold_Id"><? echo EGOLD_ID
        ?><?
        if ($require_egold_id == 2) { echo "*";
        }
        ?></label>
    <input name="F_Egold_Id" type="text" value="<? echo $F_Egold_Id ?>" maxlength="50">
</div>
<div id="divegold" style="display:none">
    <? echo JV_EGOLD_ID
    ?>
</div>
<?
}
if ($require_bank_transfer == 1 || $require_bank_transfer == 2)
{
?>
<div>
    <label for="F_Bank_Transfer"><? echo BANK_TRANSFER
        ?><?
        if ($require_bank_transfer == 2) { echo "*";
        }
        ?></label>
    <textarea name="F_Bank_Transfer" cols="30" rows="3"><? echo $F_Bank_Transfer ?></textarea>
</div>
<div id="divbanktransfer" style="display:none">
    <? echo JV_BANK_TRANSFER
    ?>
</div>
<?
}
if ($require_sponsor == 1)
{
if (empty($_COOKIE['jrox']))
{
?>
<div>
    <label for="F_Sponsor"><? echo REFERRAL_CODE
        ?>*</label>
    <input name="F_Sponsor" type="text" value="<? echo $F_Sponsor ?>" maxlength="25">
</div>
<?
}
else
{
?>
<input name="F_Sponsor" type="hidden" id="F_Sponsor" value="<? echo $F_Sponsor ?>">
<div>
    <?
    }
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
    <input name="F_Sponsor" type="hidden" id="F_Sponsor" value="<? echo $F_Sponsor ?>">
</div>
<?
}
if ($require_website_url == 1 || $require_website_url == 2)
{
?>
<div>
    <label><? echo WEBSITE_URL
        ?><?
        if ($require_website_url == 2) { echo "*";
        }
        ?></label>
    <input name="F_Web_Site" type="text" value="<? echo $F_Web_Site ?>" maxlength="100">
</div>
<div id="divweb" style="display:none">
    <? echo INVALID_WEBSITE_ADDRESS
    ?>
</div>
<?
}
if ($enable_custom_1 == 1 || $enable_custom_1 == 2)
{
?>
<div>
    <label><? echo $custom_field_1
        ?><?
        if ($enable_custom_1 == 2) { echo "*";
        }
        ?></label>
    <input name="F_Custom_Value_1" type="text" value="<? echo $F_Custom_Value_1 ?>" maxlength="255">
</div>
<div id="divcf1" style="display:none">
    <? echo ROW_ENTER." ".$custom_field_1
    ?>
</div>
<?
}
if ($enable_custom_2 == 1 || $enable_custom_2 == 2)
{
?>
<div>
    <label><? echo $custom_field_2
        ?><?
        if ($enable_custom_2 == 2) { echo "*";
        }
        ?></label>
    <input name="F_Custom_Value_2" type="text" value="<? echo $F_Custom_Value_2 ?>" maxlength="255">
</div>
<div id="divcf2" style="display:none">
    <? echo ROW_ENTER." ".$custom_field_2
    ?>
</div>
<?
}
if ($enable_custom_3 == 1 || $enable_custom_3 == 2)
{
?>
<div>
    <label><? echo $custom_field_3
        ?><?
        if ($enable_custom_3 == 2) { echo "*";
        }
        ?></label>
    <input name="F_Custom_Value_3" type="text" value="<? echo $F_Custom_Value_3 ?>" maxlength="255">
</div>
<div id="divcf3" style="display:none">
    <? echo ROW_ENTER." ".$custom_field_3
    ?>
</div>
<?
}
if ($enable_custom_4 == 1 || $enable_custom_4 == 2)
{
?>
<div>
    <label><? echo $custom_field_4
        ?> <?
        if ($enable_custom_4 == 2) { echo "*";
        }
        ?></label>
    <input name="F_Custom_Value_4" type="text" value="<? echo $F_Custom_Value_4 ?>" maxlength="255">
</div>
<div id="divcf4" style="display:none">
    <? echo ROW_ENTER." ".$custom_field_4
    ?>
</div>
<?
}
if ($enable_custom_5 == 1 || $enable_custom_5 == 2)
{
?>
<div>
    <label><? echo $custom_field_5
        ?><?
        if ($enable_custom_5 == 2) { echo "*";
        }
        ?></label>
    <input name="F_Custom_Value_5" type="text" value="<? echo $F_Custom_Value_5 ?>" maxlength="255">
</div>
<div id="divcf5" style="display:none">
    <? echo ROW_ENTER." ".$custom_field_5
    ?>
</div>
<?
}
if ($enable_membership_payment == 2)
{
?>
<div>
    <? echo MEMBERSHIP_FULL_AMOUNT
    ?>
    <? echo $membership_full_amount
    ?>
    <div>
        <label><? echo SELECT_PAYMENT_TYPE
            ?></label>
    </div>
    <? List_Processor_Options();?>
<?
 }
 if ($enable_custom_html == 1 )
 {
 ?>
 <div>
 <? echo $custom_html ?>
 </div>
 <?
 }
 if ($require_tos == 1 || $require_tos == 2)
 {
 ?>
 <div>
 <input name="F_TOS" type="checkbox" id="F_TOS" value="1">
 <?
 if ($require_tos == 2) { echo "checked";
 }
 ?>
 </div>
 <div>
 <label><? echo ACCEPT_AND_WILL_FOLLOW ?></label><a href="<? echo                     MEMBERS_HOME_BASE_URL.HOME_BASE_AFFILIATE_DIRECTORY.'/index.php?req=tos&pid=$pid' ?>"           target="_blank" data-role="dialog"><? echo TERMS_OF_SERVICE
 ?></a>
 </div>
 <?
 }
 ?>
 </div>
<div>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="<? echo SUBMIT?>">
<input name="req" type="hidden" id="req" value="newaccount">
<input name="action" type="hidden" id="action" value="signup">
<input name="pid" type="hidden" id="pid" value="<? echo $pid ?>">
</div>
</form>
<?
}
?>
```

Comment: I like how even your question has a broken HTML tag right before the code sample :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be bad HTML formatting.  I think you would be ok if you restructure the `if` block just above the problem area.  This is what I see:

```
...
if ($show_payment == 1)
{
?>
<div>
    <label>...</label>
    <? Link_Payment_Preferences();?>
    <? } else {?>
    <input name="F_Payment_Preference" type="hidden" id="F_Payment_Preference" value="check" />
</div>
<?
}
...
```

Do you see the problem?  If `$show_payment == 1`, you start a `<div>` but do not close it.  If `$show_payment != 1` (else) then you close an unopened `<div>`

**UPDATE**

So the answer is to better format your code:

```
    ...
    if ($show_payment == 1)
    {
    ?>
    <div>
        <label>...</label>
        <? Link_Payment_Preferences();?>
    </div>
        <? } else {?>
    <div>
        <label>...</label>
        <input name="F_Payment_Preference" type="hidden" id="F_Payment_Preference" value="check" />
    </div>
    <?
    }
    ...
```

See the difference? We have to close that `div` in either branch your logic takes.  Otherwise, jQuery Mobile may render some unexpected results as the DOM is not properly constructed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well for easier to read you could use also php conditionals and looping as html blocks, which makes code easier to read <?php if(true) :?> and then in en with same indention <?php endif; ?>

Comment: You are right, but the answer isn't a matter of formatting.  The OP has code that breaks the HTMLs closing elements.  My answer shows how to preserve that.  You are right that there is better ways to write out the PHP, but that alone doesn't fix the unmatched `div` closing tag